# Pass a property(id) to a component OnInit

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have two components, one order list and one order component. When you click on the order id in the order list the order component expands. I want it to expand with the data from my API. See below:

```
 <div class ="order" *ngFor="let order of orders">
     <span class="orderOrderId" (click)="showExpandedContent($event, order.orderId)">{{order.orderId}}</span>
     <app-order id="order-{{order.orderId}}" class="expandContainer"></app-order>
 </div>
```

The Order Component:

```
 @Component({
   selector: 'app-order',
   templateUrl: './order.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['../../shared-styling/main.scss','./order.component.scss'],
   providers: [OrderService]
 })

export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
 orderId: number;
 order: Order;
 errorMessage: string;

 constructor(
  private orderService: OrderService) {}

 ngOnInit(){
      this.orderService.getOrder(this.orderId)
        .subscribe( order => {
          this.order = order;},
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
 }
```

Now this doesn't work, but the code above shows basically how I want to implement it. I want to somehow send the orderId from the order list to the order component when I click on the orderId. Right now it expands the list and shows the component empty, I want to in the `<app-order>` be able to pass the orderId and onInit go get the data from my service.

How can I do this? 
Since it's a list it would have to get a new order everytime a new order id is clicked.

Comment: make use of event emitters for this if you need to pass info from one component to another

Comment: I'm not sure how I would do that, I've looked at some articles about it but it confuses me. Do you know how I would implement that on the above code?

Comment: updated with an answer

Comment: When you pass the id into the component, it should look more like this: `[orderId]="order.orderId"`. Also make sure in your `OrderComponent`, to use the `@Input()` decorator for `orderId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your template

```
 <app-order [orderId]="order.orderId" class="expandContainer"</app-order>
```

In Component use the input property

```
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
 @Input() orderId: number;
 order: Order;
 errorMessage: string;

 constructor(
  private orderService: OrderService) {}

 ngOnInit(){
      this.orderService.getOrder(this.orderId)
        .subscribe( order => {
          this.order = order;},
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
 }
```

Comment: Why did someone vote this down? @schivv Please mark this answer as solved if it did solve your issue, thx.

Comment: @Hinrich thanks but i have seen people now in SO downvoting without comment

Comment: I marked it as the answer, I couldn't do it before because it was to soon after I posted the question

Answer (score 1):

To get the `orderId` in your component, you have to declare it as an `@Input` like this:

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-order',
    templateUrl: './order.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../shared-styling/main.scss','./order.component.scss'],
    providers: [OrderService]
})

export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() orderId: number;
    order: Order;
    errorMessage: string;

    constructor(
        private orderService: OrderService) {}

    ngOnInit(){
        this.orderService.getOrder(this.orderId)
            .subscribe( order => {
                this.order = order;
            },
            error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you have to pass it to the component, like this:

```
<div class ="order" *ngFor="let order of orders">
    <span class="orderOrderId" (click)="showExpandedContent($event, order.orderId)">{{order.orderId}}</span>
    <app-order [orderId]="order.orderId" id="order-{{order.orderId}}" class="expandContainer"</app-order>
</div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for :)